# Kubernetes cluster on bare metal by kubeadm

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm, calico, bare-metal-server

I'm trying to create a single control-plane cluster with kubeadm on 3 bare metal nodes (1 master and 2 workers) running on Debian 10 with Docker as a container runtime. Each node has an external IP and internal IP.
I want to configure a cluster on the internal network and be accessible from the Internet.
Used this command for that (please correct me if something wrong):

```
kubeadm init --control-plane-endpoint=10.10.0.1 --apiserver-cert-extra-sans={public_DNS_name},10.10.0.1 --pod-network-cidr=192.168.0.0/16
```

I got:

```
kubectl get no -o wide
NAME                           STATUS   ROLES    AGE   VERSION   INTERNAL-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   OS-IMAGE                       KERNEL-VERSION   CONTAINER-RUNTIME
dev-k8s-master-0.public.dns    Ready    master   16h   v1.18.2   10.10.0.1     <none>        Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)   4.19.0-8-amd64   docker://19.3.8
```

Init phase complete successfully and the cluster is accessible from the Internet. All pods are up and running except coredns that should be running after networking will be applied.

```
kubectl apply -f https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.11/manifests/calico.yaml
```

After networking applied, coredns pods still not ready:

```
kubectl get po -A
NAMESPACE     NAME                                                   READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
kube-system   calico-kube-controllers-75d56dfc47-g8g9g               0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   192        16h
kube-system   calico-node-22gtx                                      1/1     Running            0          16h
kube-system   coredns-66bff467f8-87vd8                               0/1     Running            0          16h
kube-system   coredns-66bff467f8-mv8d9                               0/1     Running            0          16h
kube-system   etcd-dev-k8s-master-0                                  1/1     Running            0          16h
kube-system   kube-apiserver-dev-k8s-master-0                        1/1     Running            0          16h
kube-system   kube-controller-manager-dev-k8s-master-0               1/1     Running            0          16h
kube-system   kube-proxy-lp6b8                                       1/1     Running            0          16h
kube-system   kube-scheduler-dev-k8s-master-0                        1/1     Running            0          16h
```

Some logs from failed pods:

```
kubectl -n kube-system logs calico-kube-controllers-75d56dfc47-g8g9g
2020-04-22 08:24:55.853 [INFO][1] main.go 88: Loaded configuration from environment config=&config.Config{LogLevel:"info", ReconcilerPeriod:"5m", CompactionPeriod:"10m", EnabledControllers:"node", WorkloadEndpointWorkers:1, ProfileWorkers:1, PolicyWorkers:1, NodeWorkers:1, Kubeconfig:"", HealthEnabled:true, SyncNodeLabels:true, DatastoreType:"kubernetes"}
2020-04-22 08:24:55.855 [INFO][1] k8s.go 228: Using Calico IPAM
W0422 08:24:55.855525       1 client_config.go:541] Neither --kubeconfig nor --master was specified.  Using the inClusterConfig.  This might not work.
2020-04-22 08:24:55.856 [INFO][1] main.go 109: Ensuring Calico datastore is initialized
2020-04-22 08:25:05.857 [ERROR][1] client.go 255: Error getting cluster information config ClusterInformation="default" error=Get https://10.96.0.1:443/apis/crd.projectcalico.org/v1/clusterinformations/default: context deadline exceeded
2020-04-22 08:25:05.857 [FATAL][1] main.go 114: Failed to initialize Calico datastore error=Get https://10.96.0.1:443/apis/crd.projectcalico.org/v1/clusterinformations/default: context deadline exceeded
```

coredns:

```
[INFO] plugin/ready: Still waiting on: "kubernetes"
I0422 08:29:12.275344       1 trace.go:116] Trace[1050055850]: "Reflector ListAndWatch" name:pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.17.2/tools/cache/reflector.go:105 (started: 2020-04-22 08:28:42.274382393 +0000 UTC m=+59491.429700922) (total time: 30.000897581s):
Trace[1050055850]: [30.000897581s] [30.000897581s] END
E0422 08:29:12.275388       1 reflector.go:153] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.17.2/tools/cache/reflector.go:105: Failed to list *v1.Service: Get https://10.96.0.1:443/api/v1/services?limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: i/o timeout
I0422 08:29:12.276163       1 trace.go:116] Trace[188478428]: "Reflector ListAndWatch" name:pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.17.2/tools/cache/reflector.go:105 (started: 2020-04-22 08:28:42.275499997 +0000 UTC m=+59491.430818380) (total time: 30.000606394s):
Trace[188478428]: [30.000606394s] [30.000606394s] END
E0422 08:29:12.276198       1 reflector.go:153] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.17.2/tools/cache/reflector.go:105: Failed to list *v1.Namespace: Get https://10.96.0.1:443/api/v1/namespaces?limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: i/o timeout
I0422 08:29:12.277424       1 trace.go:116] Trace[16697023]: "Reflector ListAndWatch" name:pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.17.2/tools/cache/reflector.go:105 (started: 2020-04-22 08:28:42.276675998 +0000 UTC m=+59491.431994406) (total time: 30.000689778s):
Trace[16697023]: [30.000689778s] [30.000689778s] END
E0422 08:29:12.277452       1 reflector.go:153] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.17.2/tools/cache/reflector.go:105: Failed to list *v1.Endpoints: Get https://10.96.0.1:443/api/v1/endpoints?limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: i/o timeout
[INFO] plugin/ready: Still waiting on: "kubernetes"
```

Any thoughts what's wrong?

Comment: Check if firewall is blocking connection

Comment: From where to where?

Comment: Check coredns pods are deployed in worker nodes...then its worker to master

Comment: As per documentation adding workers should be done when coreDNS be up and running:
Once a Pod network has been installed, you can confirm that it is working by checking that the CoreDNS Pod is Running in the output of kubectl get pods --all-namespaces. And once the CoreDNS Pod is up and running, you can continue by joining your nodes.

Comment: ingress to the IP 10.96.0.1 is open on port 443?

Comment: What version of Docker are you running? could you check this? [Troubleshooting Kubeadm - CoreDNS pods ](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/troubleshooting-kubeadm/#coredns-pods-have-crashloopbackoff-or-error-state). Did you followed the official [Create Cluster Kubeadm](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/create-cluster-kubeadm/) guide? In order to check if it is a bug, I'd recommend you to redeploy it and see if you get the same error.

Comment: Yes, I'm following official guide.
Docker version docker://19.3.8

Comment: Have you tried redeploying already?

Comment: Yes, many times.

Comment: I've seen a similar behavior when I had multiple public interfaces on the node and calico selected the wrong one. What I did is to set IP_AUTODETECT_METHOD in the calico config https://docs.projectcalico.org/reference/node/configuration

Comment: @florin your comment looks like the correct answer to me, I encourage you to write it as an answer (and detail a little bit more if possible) as it could help others with similar issues.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is to call attention to @florin suggestion:

> I've seen a similar behavior when I had multiple public interfaces on the node and calico selected the wrong one.
>
> What I did is to set **IP_AUTODETECT_METHOD** in the calico config.

- From [Calico Configuration](https://docs.projectcalico.org/reference/node/configuration) on IP_AUTO_DETECT_METHOD:

> The method to use to autodetect the IPv4 address for this host. This is only used when the IPv4 address is being autodetected. See IP Autodetection methods for details of the valid methods.

Learn more Here: https://docs.projectcalico.org/reference/node/configuration#ip-autodetection-methods

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing same problem, but following is work for me, try this in you master node.

```
  $ sudo iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
  $ sudo iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
  $ sudo iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
  $ sudo iptables -F
```